# wget creating empty file

Tags: python, bash, wget

I wrote a program in bash (which calls another program in Python) to pull information from http://www.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3021-activnyse-actives.html into an .html file, which then converts it into .xhtml and then .csv. This runs through a loop so that it repeats the process every minute or so for an hour. Below is the bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=0
while [ $n -lt 60 ]
do
    filename="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")"
    wget -O - http://www.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3021-activnyse-actives.html > "$filename.html"
    java -jar tagsoup-1.2.1.jar --files "$filename.html"
    python xhtmlToCsv.py "$filename.xhtml" > "$filename.csv"
    ((n++))
    sleep 60
done
```

And here is the Python program it calls:

```
import sys
import xml.dom.minidom

document = xml.dom.minidom.parse(sys.argv[1])
tableElements = document.getElementsByTagName('table')

print "exchange,symbol,company,volume,price,change"
lines = tableElements[2].getElementsByTagName('td')
n = 0
data = [None] * 6

for i in lines:
    if n % 6 == 1:
        del data[:]
        data = [None] * 6

    for node in i.childNodes:
        if n % 6 + 1 < 6:
            data[n%6+1] = node.nodeValue
            if n%6+1 == 3:
                data[n%6+1] = data[n%6+1].replace(",", "")

    for items in i.getElementsByTagName('a'):
        j = i.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]
        for node in j.childNodes:
            data[0] = 'NYSE'
            data[1] = node.nodeValue[node.nodeValue.index('(')+1:node.nodeValue.index(')')]
            data[2] = node.nodeValue[0:node.nodeValue.index(" (")]

    if n % 6 == 5 and n > 6:
        print data[0] + "," + data[1] + "," + data[2] + "," + data[3] + "," + data[4] + "," + data[5]   
    n+=1
```

What I don't get, though, is why approximately every third .html file generated by the code returns an empty file. Is there something wrong with the code, or is it just my connection? If it is just the connection, is there a way I can throw out the empty file and try again?

Comment: You would have way better control over error conditions by writing the whole thing in Python. You can use `requests` (or plain `urllib2`) to grab the data and `BeautifulSoup` to navigate the HTML "tag soup".

Comment: use `print()` to display values in variable and which part of code is executed - it helps to find problem. Or learn how to use debuger.

Comment: first you should read all data from file and check if you get something or you get empty string. And then you can `exit()` with error code which you can use in bash to download file again. But it would be easier if you use python instead of `wget` and `java` to download file and get data.

Comment: Another way to strip formatting is to use `lynx -dump`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I figured it out. All I had to do was do a line count for the resulting .csv file, and if it was only 1, that would indicate no data got transferred, and so the files for that iteration would be thrown out.

```
a=($(wc $filename.csv))
x=${a[0]}
if [ $x -eq 1 ]
then
    rm $filename.html
    rm $filename.xhtml
    rm $filename.csv
else
    ((n++))
    sleep 60
fi
```

Thanks everyone for your input.